# Scala: behavior of filter on Iterator vs. List

Tags: list, scala, filter, iterator

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Iterator(2,4,6)
res0: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> res0.filter
filter      filterNot

scala> res0.filter
                                           def filter(p: A => Boolean): Iterator[A]
```

// Given this definition of filter, I would expect the below expression (1) to work:

```
scala> Iterator(2,4,6).filter(Set(1,2,3).contains).toSet
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2)
```

// **Question # 1:** How does the below expression (2) work ? Where does it get the `A => Boolean` inference from ? I meant to ask, where's the Boolean coming from ?

```
scala> Iterator(2,4,6).filter(Set(1,2,3)).toSet
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2)
```

// **Question # 2**: Which one is better expression (1) vs (2) and why ?

// Tried the same thing on List and I expected this to work.

```
 scala> List(2,4,6).filter(List(1,2,3).contains)
    res3: List[Int] = List(2)
```

// **Question # 3:** Why doesn't this work when it magically worked for Iterator ?

```
scala>  List(2,4,6).filter(List(1,2,3))
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Boolean
               List(2,4,6).filter(List(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question # 1: How does the below expression (2) work ? Where does it get the A => Boolean inference from ? I meant to ask, where's the Boolean coming from ?

`Set[A] extends (A) => Boolean`, so `Set(1, 2, 3)` *is* a function `A => Boolean`. We can easily see, as it has an apply method that tests whether or not an element is contained in the `Set`.

```
scala> Set(1, 2, 3)(2)
res22: Boolean = true
```

> Question # 2: Which one is better expression (1) vs (2) and why ? Tried the same thing on List and I expected this to work.

Which one is better is more a matter of opinion--functionally they are exactly the same. For those familiar with `Set`, it should be clear what either does (they are both equivalent to `contains`). One *might* say using `Set(1, 2, 3).contains` makes it more apparent as to what it does. A `List` has an apply method, but not the same as `Set`. `List#apply` is `Int => A` -- a method to retrieve an element from the `List` by index. So for lists, you must use `contains`.

> Question # 3: Why doesn't this work when it magically worked for Iterator ?

This is really the same as **#2**. `List(1, 2, 3).apply` is not `Int => Boolean`, it is `Int => Int`.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer #1**

The reason `filter(Set(1,2,3))` works is that `Set` has an `apply` method that shadows `contains`:

```
class Set[T] { 
  def apply(elem: T): Boolean
}
```

**Answer #2**

They are identical.

**Answer #3**

That is also why `List(2,4,6).filter(List(1,2,3))` does not work. If you tried `List(2,4,6).filter(Set(1,2,3))` instead it would work. List's apply is an accessor to a position in the list:

```
class List[T] {
  def apply(n: Int): Int
}
```